# Packaging Javascript files in a war?

Tags: java, javascript, maven-2

I am developing a Servlet based Java project which is to be packaged as a war using Maven.
Is there a way I can include JavaScript (JS) files along with this project (they should be available at some url when the project loads on a Tomcat Server).

I have looked around but have not found any working solutions.

Comment: This is a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397357/copy-a-file-during-maven-build-phase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the better solution is to stick to Maven convention, which specifies that the root directory of your Web application is `src/main/webapp`.

So if you put all your Javascript files in `src/main/webapp/javascript` (or `src/main/webapp/js`), they will be integrated in your final war package.

In the Maven WAR plugin, they give some descriptions (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) for example) about the content of the directories. For example:

```
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.jsp
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

As you can see, you can put resources in `webapp/xxx` directory, such as `jsp` file here.

As stated by cuh, you can also configure the Maven WAR plugin if your directory structure is different.

Comment: You are right, my example-config somehow mixes external with implicit resource adding. Everything under `src/main/resources` is added by default to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. So it would be added twice to the `war`. btw the maven convention is `src/main/webapp` not webapps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and configure it something like this:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
       <configuration>
           <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
           <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>your/path/to/js</directory>
                    <targetPath>js</targetPath>
                </resource>
           </webResources>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

**edit**: You probably don't want to include the `js` into the `classes` Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in directories under src/main/webapp.  That is, assuming you generated it using the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype.

My current app has them under src/main/webapp/javascript, and accesses them in JSPs like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

(for jsp files in src/main/webapp that is)