# Copy a file during maven build phase

Tags: java, maven, war

My situation is:

- I have a Maven project, I have my java classes in **/app/src/main/java**, my resources in **/app/src/main/resources** and my webapp files in **/app/src/main/webapp**
- I have a javascript file in **/common/script.js**

Now what I want is to include (copy) the javascript file to the war file during the build phase of maven. To be precise, I want the **script.js** to land in **/js/** directory of the war archive, just as it was placed in **/app/src/main/webapp/js** before starting the build.

I need this to share one version of resource files among many web-apps.

Kind regards,
Q.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying file from one project to another in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386543/copying-file-from-one-project-to-another-in-maven)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this, as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
              <directory>../common</directory>
              <targetPath>/js</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: this won't exclude the default resource directory **/src/main/resources**, will it?

Comment: @Queequeg. No. This will include additional resources not present in the default `resources` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mojo copy-resources to copy resources which are not in the default maven layout or not declared in the build/resources element.

Check

["maven-resources-plugin"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maven-resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to copy a file to the desired location. Before or after a war has been built